# How can I make the bibliography header to look the same as the others?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, header-footer, fancyhdr, biber

If you compile this MWE with `Biber` and `pdflatex` you will see that the header of the bibliography is rendered in all caps like this: "REFERENCES". How can I make it look the same as the other headers of the normal sections?

```
\documentclass[%
    10pt,%
    twocolumn%
]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, textcase, letterspace, lipsum}


% +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
% |Bibliography                                                       |
% +-------------------------------------------------------------------+

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\long\def\etb@listitem#1#2{%
    \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\@gobble#2}
    {}{\expandafter\etb@listitem@i
        \expandafter{\@secondoftwo#2}{#1}}}
\long\def\etb@listitem@i#1#2{#2{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[autostyle, italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

% +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
% |Headers                                                            |
% +-------------------------------------------------------------------+

%%
% Improved letterspacing of small caps and all-caps text.
%

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsmallcaps}{\scshape}

% Set up letterspacing (using microtype package) -- requires pdfTeX v1.40+
\newcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[200]{#1}}
\newcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[50]{#1}}
\newcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\textls[200]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[R]{\makebox[\columnwidth][l]{\smallcaps{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[L]{\makebox[\columnwidth][r]{\smallcaps{title}}}
\fancyhead[C]{\smallcaps{~-~}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


\begin{document}
    \section{A}
    \lipsum[1-6]\textcite{a:b}
    \section{B}
     \lipsum[1-5]
     \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### bibliography.bib

```
@online{a:b,
    author = {{Author}},
    shortauthor={AA},
    title  = {},
    year  = {2013},
    url  = {},
    urldate = {2018-02-28},
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by redefining the `bibheading`:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex` 3.8 and above have the semi-official `\abx@MakeMarkcase` to control the typesetting of the section marks.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\abx@MakeMarkcase}[1]{#1}
\makeatother
```

should do what you want.

Comment: What does 'semi-official' mean? And shouldn't we avoid using `biblatex` internals where possible? What's the advantage of this method? So many questions. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn Semi official means that past me was a bit too reluctant to drop the `@` and find a proper user-level name for the macro (and to document it, see the discussion in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/627). In general internals should be avoided, or rather: user level macros should be preferred, but `abx`-macros are okayish in some situations, see §4.11.10 *Namespaces*. The advantage is that this works for all headings at once. So if I use `\printbiblist` I don't have to redefine `\defbibheading{biblist}`, same for `bibintoc`.